# OpenVPN can ping internet but can't browse

Tags: openvpn

I have the same configuration of my OpenVPN server since two years, and I just copy paste each time I upgrade the server. But this time it doesn't work anymore.

I can connect with my clients, and I can ping outside internet: with domain name or with ip address (what it mean that the domain resolution works). I can also ping to vpn server ip, or router in the server network.

But I can't browse outside internet or inside openvpn network. The only site where I can browse is into openvpn router (at 192.168.45.1).

My openvpn conf:

```
dev tun
#dev tap0
client-config-dir ccd
local 192.168.45.5 # SWAP THIS NUMBER WITH YOUR RASPBERRY PI IP ADDRESS 
proto udp #Some people prefer to use tcp. Don't change it if you don't know.
port 1194 
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt 
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server.crt # SWAP WITH YOUR CRT NAME
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server.key # SWAP WITH YOUR KEY NAME
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/dh2048.pem # If you changed to 2048, change that here!
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 
# server and remote endpoints 
ifconfig 10.8.0.1 10.8.0.2 
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Server 
push "route 10.8.0.1 255.255.255.255" 
# Add route to Client routing table for the OpenVPN Subnet 
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0" 
# your local subnet 
push "route 192.168.45.5 255.255.255.0" # SWAP THE IP NUMBER WITH YOUR RASPBERRY PI IP ADDRESS
# Set primary domain name server address to the SOHO Router 
# If your router does not do DNS, you can use Google DNS 8.8.8.8 
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.45.1" # This should already match your router address and not need to be changed.
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and 
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of 
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway. 
push "redirect-gateway def1" 
client-to-client 
duplicate-cn 
keepalive 5 30 
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key 0 
cipher AES-256-CBC 
comp-lzo 
user nobody 
group nogroup 
persist-key 
persist-tun 
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20 
log /var/log/openvpn.log 
verb 3
```

I have a file `/etc/firewall-openvpn-rules.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.45.5
```

And in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        pre-up /etc/firewall-openvpn-rules.sh
 address 192.168.45.5
 gateway 192.168.45.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.45.0
 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

And `iptables -L -v` return:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 18750 packets, 4000K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 14757 packets, 6103K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   dns0    anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  dns0   eth0    anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 20662 packets, 8124K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi,

I installed Tinc network today in my server and now the OpenVPN server redirects the traffic well..

I don't know what happen, but after months having this, problem now it redirects correctly the traffic and works well...

So now I have two VPN working, one with Tinc and the other with OpenVPN.

Strange things...

Thanks anyway